# Migrating from eclipse to Android studio "Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found"

Tags: android, eclipse

I tried to import my eclipse project into Android studio. But I stuck in this error.

"Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'android' not found"

Below is my gradle build.

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':Downloads:PdfLib')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
```

}

Comment: Try this on your app gradle
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "your package name or application id"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

Answer (score 1):

Try this on your app gradle .You got this error because you never defined you application id..

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "your application id or package name"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }
}
```

then depencies

Comment: Then accept my answer..So it can be useful to someone else having same issue.